# Sending intents without using a specific activity to go from android

Tags: android, class, import

I'm not sure if this is possible just something I'm working on. I have a app preferences class that's imported into my activity. From that class I run a check internet connection function that if returned null I send an intent to another activity. Problem is I want to run this function throughout my app is there a way to get the name of the current activity and  pass it to the appspreferences class and place it within the intent.

Here is my function so far

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   


private ConnectivityManager getSystemService(String connectivityService) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public void checkInternet(){

    isOnline();

    if(isOnline() == false){

        this.getClass().getSimpleName();

Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(this.getClass().getSimpleName().this,Network.class);
        this.getClass().getSimpleName().this.startActivity(connectionIntent);
        this.getClass().getSimpleName().this.finish();  

    }
    Log.v("Pref", "checking internet");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try sending context of current Activity as parameter to your method

calling class

```
Context myContext = this;
obj.checkInternet(myContext);
```

common Class which can be called by all classes to check for internet

```
    public void checkInternet(Context myContext){

    isOnline();

    if(isOnline() == false){

Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(myContext,Network.class);
        startActivity(connectionIntent);
        myContext.finish();  

    }
    Log.v("Pref", "checking internet");
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i think i understand the logic of what your saying but i'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: hi i have edited my code with how i have tried to implement it but still erroring in eclipse